# Change Image color dynamically using CSS property

Tags: jquery, css, extjs

In one of my application, I need to make UI customization dynamically. I can change the font color, background colour..., But Is there is any way to change the image colour dynamically with out reloading the image. I am using CSS3.

Comment: What do you mean to change the image color?

Comment: How do you want to change the color of an image? From black&white to color? (or the other way)

Comment: you want to turn your image to black and white ? Because that's the only way you can do it by CSS

Comment: This is depend on user selection. I have some button in my page. that uses some image with different shape. Suppose a user chosse different color scheme, then i need to apply that color to the button as well.

Comment: So you're talking about the backgorund color of a button? Not background image? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: No. Image color should change based on the background color. I cannot set backgorund color.

Comment: You do know that a button doesn't have a background image, but has as much a background color as any other element on your page? Maybe you could upload a screenshot or JSfiddle so we can see what you mean, because it seems you don't know what to call some things.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS3 it's pretty easy to change an image to grayscale from color or the other way around. You can apply the `filter` property to an object and with that adapt the image. Does NOT work in Internet Explorer and Opera Mini ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters))

```
img:hover.desaturate { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

And just apply the class to an image you want to desaturate:

```
<img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" class="desaturate"/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tu62ua1m/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `filter` property. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/ There are a lot of things you can do with this, but don't forget to check it for browser compatibility.